# Redundancy In Definition of Uniform Integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, uniform-integrability

In his notes [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) on modes of convergence for measurable functions $f_n : X \to \mathbb{C}$, Terry Tao provides the following definition of uniform integrability:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space (of possibly infinite measure), and let $f_n : X \to \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of absolutely integrable functions. The $f_n$ are said to be **uniformly integrable** if the following three statements hold:
>
> 1. (Uniform bound on $L^1$ norm) One has $$\sup_n\|f_n\|_{L^1} = \sup_n\int_X|f_n|\,d\mu < +\infty.$$
> 2. (No escape to vertical infinity) One has $$\sup_n \int_{|f_n| \geq M} |f_n|\,d\mu \to 0$$ as $M \to +\infty$.
> 3. (No escape to width or horizontal infinity) For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a finite measure subset $E$ of $X$ such that $$\int_{X \setminus E} |f_n|\,d\mu \leq \epsilon$$ for all $n$.

Are all three of these statements necessary? I believe we can prove the first from the second and third as follows: Pick $M > 0$ and $E \in \mathcal{B}$ of finite measure such that $\int_{|f_n| \geq M} |f_n|\,d\mu \leq 1$ and $\int_{X \setminus E} |f_n|\,d\mu \leq 1$ for all $n$. Then for all $n$ we can write $$\int_X |f_n|\,d\mu \leq \int_{X \setminus E} |f_n|\,d\mu + \int_{|f_n| \geq M} |f_n|\,d\mu + \int_{E \cap \{|f_n| < M\}} |f_n|\,d\mu \leq 1 + 1 + M\mu(E),$$thus obtaining a uniform bound for the $\|f_n\|_{L^1}$. Am I making a mistake in this argument, or is this definition for uniform integrability in fact redundant?

Comment: The first one is certainly not sufficient for uniform integrability and the standard definition is what you wrote in the 2nd one. For example, just take $f_{n}=n\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ . Then this is uniformly bounded in $L^{1}$ but this is not an uniformly integrable family.

Comment: The 3rd one is implied by the 2nd one. But for the 3rd to imply the 2nd, one needs an additional uniform $L^{1}$ boundedness alongwith finiteness of the measure space.

Comment: [This](https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Uniform.html) imo has over the years served as perhaps the best short article on uniform integrability and also has some additions that are my own (after conversations with the author).

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I agree with you for the case when $X$ has finite measure, but when $X$ has infinite measure can't we come up with examples of sequences which satisfy the 2rd condition but not the 3rd? E.g. $f_n = (1/n)1_{[0,n]}$ when $X = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Sorry, I misread your 3rd  condition. It is given in Royden as tightness under the section vitali convergence theorem and is certainly not implied by uniform integrability and neither is uniform integrability implied by it. This "tightness" is not the same as one understands tightness in case of probability measures.

Comment: And yes 2+3 implies 1.